# Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string

Tags: php, wordpress, breadcrumbs

**Problem**

> Catchable fatal error:  Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home/user/public_html/wp-content/themes/themename/functions/views/frontend/content-breadcrumb.php on line 58

Now on Line 58 of that file

```
<a href="<?php echo get_term_link($category->slug,$category->taxonomy) ?>"><?php echo $category->name ?></a> >
```

In wp_terms : Slug  is axl
and in wp_term_taxanomy: taxanomy is product_bisbrand.

Both the values seems ok.

On frontend the error seems like this:

[image]

**Solution Tried :**

Converting the wp_term table and wp_term_taxanomy table into utf8_general_ci

But it didn't worked.

Note: I am not a coder, if you require any other info i will provide you.

Answer (score 0):

`get_term_link` could return string or WP_Error. To understand what exacly goes wrong use this code:

```
$termLink = get_term_link($category->slug,$category->taxonomy);
if(is_wp_error( $termLink )){
    echo 'Error!<br/>';
    var_dump($termLink);
    var_dump($category);
} else {
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($category->slug,$category->taxonomy) ?>"><?php echo $category->name ?></a> >
    <?php
}
```

Comment: `Error!
object(WP_Error)#352 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["invalid_term"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "Empty Term" } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }`

Comment: In `get_term_link` slug or/and taxonomy are invalid. Show me output form `var_dump($category)`. Var_dump get_terms() to see all terms.